# Почему 3 разных компоновки в объявлении одной переменной не приводят к ошибке?

Tags: c++, компоновщик

```
static auto i{0};

int main() {
  auto i{0};
  { extern int i; }
}
```

Почему можно трижды объявить одну и ту же переменную с разными компоновками и [не получить ошибку](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:6),source:%27static+auto+i%7B0%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+i%7B0%7D%3B%0A++++%7B+extern+int+i%3B+%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)? Какая в итоге компоновка будет у переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю о какой компоновке вы говорите. Но у этих переменных разная область видимости, поэтому при объявлении нет ошибки.

```
static auto i{0}; // глобальная область видимости

int main() 
{
  auto i{0}; // область видимости в пределах функции main()
  {                    // начало блока
     extern int i;     // область видимости в блоке, но переменная из другого блока трансляции
  }                    // конец блока
  for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) // область видимости в блоке, которым является цикл
  {
     if(i<5) // используется переменная, объявленная в цикле
     {}
  }
}
```

Локальные переменные при использовании имеют приоритет над глобальными. Т.е. при использовании внутри блока, будет использоваться переменная, объявленная в блоке.
Но при использовании всё равно может появиться ошибка - когда компилятор не сможет определить, о какой именно переменной идет речь. При этом, это не самое плохое - хуже когда компилятор сам определился, какую переменную использовать, но это не совпадает с ожиданием программиста. Поэтому лучше не допускать совпадения имен.
А вот так у вас будут проблемы, т.к. область видимости одинаковая и компилятор не сможет выбрать, какую именно из этих переменных использовать.

```
static auto i{0};
extern int i;

int main() 
{
     if(i<5) // О какой из двух i идет речь?
     {}
}
```

Comment: Означают ли одноимённые переменные одну и ту же штуку определяется компоновкой (linkage). Для static и extern это внутренняя и внешняя компоновка, а для "локальных" переменных - отсутствие компоновки (no linkage). В вопросе я добавил 3 разных компоновки, но не получил ошибку. Почему так?

Comment: Скорее всего вы получите ошибку, когда попытаетесь использовать их и у компилятора окажутся 2 переменные в одной области видимости - он не сможет сам выбрать, какую переменную использовать. Переменные определяются 3 параметрами - время жизни, область видимости и компоновка. Так вот какую именно переменную использовать определяется областью видимости. Например у 3 переменной область видимости - внутри блока. Внутри блока компилятор будет использовать переменную, объявленную в другой единице трансляции (в другом файле). У него нет проблем с выбором.

Comment: Второй пример компилируется и исполняется нормально на годболте.

Comment: Тогда вопрос - какая i проверяется в цикле? У вас есть в `if()` какие-то осмысленные действия? Если нет - скорее всего оптимизатор просто выкинул это из кода. А у вас есть ещё один файл с кодом, в котором объявлена i, которая в этом файле `extern`? Если нет, то она тоже выкинута из итогового кода.